# Spring Data Redis - Lettuce Connection Pool Setting

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

Trying to setup Lettuce Connection Pool in spring data redis environment.
Below is the code

```
    @Bean
     LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(GenericObjectPoolConfig genericObjectPoolConfig) {


        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisConfiguration.setHostName(hostName);
        redisConfiguration.setPort(port);
        redisConfiguration.setPassword(password);
        redisConfiguration.setDatabase(databaseIndex);
        LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration= LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder().poolConfig(genericObjectPoolConfig).build();
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration,lettuceClientConfiguration);
    }

@Bean
    public GenericObjectPoolConfig genericObjectPoolConfig(){
        GenericObjectPoolConfig genericObjectPoolConfig=new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(100);
        return genericObjectPoolConfig;
    }
```

When I checked the execution it is not considering the Connection pool and every time connection is established.  Any pointer on this?

Comment: What makes you say that it doesn't consider the connection pool? `setMaxTotal(100)` should result in a pool of a 100 connections maximum. Perhaps that's what you're seeing? Have you tried setting it to a much lower number and observe? Default is 8.

Comment: I used similar code with `LettucePoolingClientConfiguration` and 1. I didn't see a lot of connections to my Redis (like with Jedis), connection(s) were blocked and everything worked waaay slower than with Jedis.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments of LettuceConnectionFactory:

> This factory creates a new LettuceConnection on each call to getConnection(). Multiple LettuceConnections share a single thread-safe native connection by default.

Also refer to another question: [Redis connection pool configured using spring-data-redis but not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684915/redis-connection-pool-configured-using-spring-data-redis-but-not-working-correct)

We could say that if your application connects to only one redis server/cluster, you want to keep the default. Otherwise, for example and especially when you are developing a multi-tenancy application, you can set shareNativeConnection to false and use a pool (with minIdle set to 0 and minEvictableIdleDuration a proper value).